# jQuery event.prevent only at #

Tags: jquery

I've got this function:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("nav a").click(function(evn){     
        evn.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);
    });
 });
```

My navigation got some links and some "#"ankers.
When I add the function, all the links don't work, how can I change the function, so that the function only works when the href="" got an "#" in it?

I hope you can help me.

Edit: is an an example: https://jsfiddle.net/cq4krz0w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to only target `<a>` tags with `href` attributes that contain an anchor :

```
// Only target <a> elements with an href that contains an anchor
$("nav a[href*='#']").click(function(){     
    // Scroll using your preferred approach here
});
```

You could use a [starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `a[href^='#']` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

In your existing code you can put check on `event.target.attributes.href.value` and detect if it contains '#'